# How can I make an element place itself, depending on its value, at the top of a bar?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to the world of `d3.js` and I am trying that depending on the numeric value generated when clicking on the `generateNumber` function, an image is put where it corresponds. Obviously, if the value is 100, it must be in the highest part of the bar, and otherwise if is zero in the lowest part. I intend to make this dynamic depending on the size of the bar.

If it is not too much trouble, I would like to put a text in front of the image indicating the number that the function generated.

this is my live code:
https://jsfiddle.net/891vzjct/1/

[image]

```
<div id="visualization"></div>
  <button onclick="generateNumber()">
   Generate number
  </button>
</div>


function generateNumber(){
  let number=Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);;
  console.log(number);
  console.log(yScale(number));
  d3.select("#indicador").attr("y",yScale(number));
}

let heightRectangle=10;
d3.select("#visualization").append('svg')
var vis = d3.select("svg").attr("width",800).attr("height",614).style("border","1px solid red");

 vis.append("image")
     .attr("id","indicador")
    .attr("href","https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/08/17/86784_left_512x512.png")
    .attr("width",30)
    .attr("height",30)
    .style("transform","scale(0.5) translate(113px)")



//Doing my color bar
var arr = d3.range(101)
let maxRange=600;
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([maxRange,0])

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,50,100])
    .range(["green", "yellow", "red"])

vis.selectAll('rect').data(arr).enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        y : function(d,i) {  console.log(d,yScale(d)); return i*+4 },
        x : 20,
        height: heightRectangle,
        width: 40,
        fill: function(d) { return colorScale(d) }
    });


    /*
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([300, 0])
      .domain([100, 0]);

    var yAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(y)
      .ticks(5);

    vis.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("axis title");*/
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you want. so are you trying to put the number text on top of the bar? or next to the #indicador?

Comment: @soundquiet  he wants put the number text next to #indicador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a text in front of the image(#indicador), you can append a `text` and then change the attr `y` and `text` in the `generateNumber()` function, basically the same as what you did to the image(#indicador).
A working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jdakt2se/26/).

Also I changed some code from yours.

1. the `maxRange` is 410 in your case, instead of 600 according to the rectangles generated.
2. I removed the `scale(0.5)` of the image since I can just set the width and height to 15px. If you try to scale, take care of the transform-origin.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for! thank you. I have two last doubts, I hope I don't bother you. Why do you know that `maxRange` must be equal to `410`? and I am trying to migrate my code to `version 5` of `d3.js` I replace `d3.scale.linear()` with `d3.scaleLinear () `and nothing happens .. thanks for your help

Comment: @yavg for the `410`, I just see it from inspect and the last rectangle's `y` is 400 and `width` 10, so the bottom of the bar is 410. For the v5, can you give a code example?

Comment: great! Thank you very much, that's the problem, in my real project I have the `v5`, if I do what I told you I don't get errors, but it doesn't work either. https://jsfiddle.net/ue6qLaj3/  this fiddle has `v5`

Comment: @yavg Oh, list the attr of rect one by one will solve it. selection.attr(object) no longer works https://jsfiddle.net/cv1yqobw/5/